# C'è una ragione per cui un insieme di *clienti* è chiamato *clientela*, ma un insieme di *utenti* è chiamato *utenza* e non *utentela*?

Tags: etymology

C'è una ragione per cui un insieme di *clienti* è chiamato *clientela*, ma un insieme di *utenti* è chiamato *utenza* e non *utentela*?

Comment: Allora perché non _clienza_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In italiano, come, direi, in ogni lingua europea, non esistono regole univoche per derivare sostantivi da altri sostantivi, sostantivi da verbi ecc. e anche le regolarità che esistono sono difficili da generalizzare.

Già in latino non esistevano regole simili e regolarità e irregolarità del latino determinano molte delle coerenze e delle incoerenze dell'italiano. Qui si tratta proprio di un caso di questo tipo.

Anche se in latino **ūtēntia* non è attestato, trarre *utenza* da *utente* (lat. *ūtēns*, participio presente del verbo *ūtor*) significa seguire una regolarità frequente in quella lingua: *īnfāns* dà *īnfantia*, *dēmēns* dà *dēmentia*, *violens* dà *violentia* ecc. Tra l'altro non è un caso che **ūtēntia* non esistesse in latino: è un concetto moderno legato all'economia dei servizi, mentre *ūtēns* era usato in un altro senso.

La parola *clientēla*, da *cliens*, è invece attestata già in latino. Questo perché le clientele di un senatore esistevano già nell'antica Roma, "l'utenza dell'Anfiteatro Flavio" non è invece un concetto che abbia molto senso in quella società:

> scis quam diligam Siculos et quam illam clientelam honestam iudicem.

(Questo è Cicerone che dice quanto gli piacciono i siculi e le loro oneste clientele...)

*Clientēla* assomiglia a parole come *tūtēla*, *querēla*, *loquēla*, *corruptēla* ecc., che sono tutte rimaste simili in italiano. Anche *candēla* e *tēla* sono formate con lo stesso suffisso a partire da verbi che significano "splendere" e "tessere", anche se al parlante italiano questa origine non sembra più ovvia. Da quel calco ci si è inventati in latino medievale la parola che è arrivata in italiano: *curatela*, invece di **curanza* (anche se esiste *noncuranza*!). Che l'imporsi di un suffisso piuttosto che un altro sia arbitrario si vede dalla coppia *loquela*/*eloquenza*, dove la differenza di significato è data solo dal prefisso *e-*.

Il concetto in tutti questi esempi non è "insieme di X", ma è semplicemente la sostantivazione di un verbo (sembra la sostantivazione di un sostantivo a volte, ma solo perché quel sostantivo è a sua volta un participio presente che si è cristallizzato come sostantivo a sé stante). In italiano come in latino spesso si usa la stessa parola per indicare l'astrazione di un verbo e l'insieme di coloro che eseguono ciò che quel verbo indica. Mi spiego: la clientela non è solo l'insieme di coloro che fanno i clienti di qualcuno, ma è anche il rapporto (di clientela, appunto) che lega ciascuno di loro alla persona cui si rivolgono; l'utenza non è solo l'insieme degli utenti ma è anche il rapporto tra utente e fornitore, infatti se mi tagliano la luce si dice che mi hanno "sospeso l'utenza", anche se ciò riguarda solo me.

Conclusione: se una parola derivata esisteva già in latino classico, la cosa più probabile è che sia rimasta tale in italiano, portandosi dietro eventuali irregolarità latine; se non esisteva, quando è servita è stata derivata ricalcando altre derivazioni già esistenti e lì spesso ci sono vari suffissi candidati e l'evoluzione della lingua prende una strada che se non è del tutto casuale poco ci manca. Tra l'altro spesso queste scelte arbitrarie non sono avvenute in italiano ma altrove e sono arrivate in italiano tramite il latino medievale, il francese o altre lingue romanze.

Comment: Grande risposta!

Comment: La frase di Cicerone non dovrebbe essere "... e quanto giudichi onesta quella clientela"?

Comment: Sì, non ho dato una traduzione vera e propria, che sarebbe qualcosa come «Sai quanto mi piacciano i Siculi e quanto reputi onesta la loro clientela».

Comment: Scusa, il mio latino è molto arrugginito, ma dove sarebbe "la loro"?

Comment: Non è così arrugginito: non c'è, letteralmente dice «quella clientela». Ma quella clientela è, appunto, la loro. Non tradurrei letteralmente perché cosa indichi qui la parola "clientela" non è così chiaro in italiano; anzi, volendo fare una buona traduzione direi: «Sai quanto mi piacciano i Siculi e quanto li reputi onesti come clienti».